# Is redeem correctly use here?

Tags: word-usage

I've checked the dictionary on "redeem", but I'm not sure if I understand how to use it.

> **Redeem:** gain or regain possession of (something) in exchange for payment.

Fictitiously, let's say you offer a consultation at $10. Customer will receive a $10 voucher after the consultation. The $10 can be used to sign up for Package-ABC only. Package-ABC costs $30.

Given the context above, is the word "Redeem" correctly used here?

> 1. You can redeem the $10 voucher to sign up for Package-ABC.
> 2. You can redeem Package-ABC with the $10 voucher.
> 3. The $10 voucher is redeemable for Package-ABC.
> 4. The $10 voucher can be redeemed for Package-ABC
> 5. $10 voucher redeemable for Package-ABC

Or simply

> 6. You can use the $10 voucher for Package-ABC
> 7. You will receive $10 voucher for Package-ABC
> 8. The $10 voucher can be used for Package-ABC

Comment: Have you looked at actual sentences that use the word? If you have questions about how it is being used in those sentences, then please indicate (in your question, not in a comment) what the source of confusion is. Simply asking whether sentences use a word correctly is a request for proofreading, which is off-topic here.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the phrase "$10 voucher". If you can use the voucher to buy a $30 package, then it was apparently a $30 voucher, not a $10 voucher. Or are you saying that this voucher gives you a $10 discount on the package? In that case, we'll usually use the word "toward" or "towards" somewhere in there.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan It wasn't a request for proofreading but attempts to understand how the word should be used.

Comment: Thanks @ruakh Yes I meant a $10 discount for Package-ABC. That's where I am confused. I can redeem an item with a voucher. However, what if the voucher is not a full value of the item, can I still use redeem in that scenario? I couldn't figure out where the word "toward(s)" fit in. *The $10 voucher is redeemable towards Package-ABC?*

Comment: @PlainH2O I am just trying to help you prevent this question being closed. (It already has 3 out of 5 close votes.) Please see [this page](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for an expanation of why you should identify your specific source of concern rather than just ask whether sentences are correct or not. (It also has useful advice about how to ask good questions.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question!

Most of your examples seem *technically* correct to me — the only one that doesn't is "You can redeem Package-ABC with the $10 voucher" — but most of them feel a bit awkward, and I had to think about it for a while to figure out why I think that is.

Specifically, I think the problem is that "$10 voucher" means "voucher redeemable for something worth $10", so it's awkward to call it a "$10 voucher" *and* say what it can be redeemed for. Instead, you should just call it a "voucher", and put the "$10" in the description of what it can be redeemed for. For example:

> You'll receive a voucher for $10 off your first month of Package-ABC.

or:

> You will receive a voucher redeemable for $10 toward a new subscription to Package-ABC.

But if you really want to call it a "$10 voucher", I think something like this would be pretty OK:

> You'll receive a $10 voucher to use toward a new subscription to Package-ABC.

---

**Edited to add:** The definition of *redeem* that you've quoted is *not* the definition for the sense you're interested in. (Hat-tip to LawrenceC for noticing this.) The definition that you've quoted is for the sense found in the context of, for example, a [pawn shop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawnbroker). The sense that you're interested in is sense 5b(2) at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redeem: "to exchange for something of value", with the example "*redeem* trading stamps".

Answer (score 0):

> Redeem: gain or regain possession of (something) in exchange for payment.

Find a different dictionary.

Specifically, what *redeem* usually means is to trade some sort of non-cash/check/credit instrument - something that is *not* money for something, a discount on something, or the right to do something (such as attend an event).

Things that are redeemed typically include codes, tickets, vouchers, slips, and tokens.

If you trade money to buy something, that's a *purchase*, not a redemption.

Examples 1, 3, 4, and 5 are good.  Vouchers are absolutely a common thing to redeem.

In example 2 - packages are not a common thing to redeem.  You want to use *get* or equivalent here.

In *redeem X*, X can't mean the object you want, it's always the object you are using to get the object you want.

Comment: To be clear, the definition that the OP quotes *is* a correct definition of the word "redeem", corresponding to sense 1a at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redeem; but you make a good point, because that's not the sense that the OP is interested in (which is sense 5b(2) at that page).